# Loading New Document Versions

Tags: document, library, versioning

Can we select an existing document and load a new version rather than just loading a document with the same name and advising to replace the current document?

I am concerned that new versions of existing doc's won't be picked up if the filename is slightly different; to avoid this we would rather select an existing doc and choose to upload a new version.

Comment: I have the very same requirement/concern and so far that's the only question i found about this topic. I'm still searching but it looks like a issue solved by custom development: a custom edit form that allows to upload a new file ontop of the existing document